# Command in ISE differs from Command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Really Strange, Run the following command from a Standard PowerShell Prompt

```
Get-ComputerInfo
```

Returns a large list of properties

```
WindowsBuildLabEx                                       : 14393.447.amd64fre.rs1_release_inmarket.161102-0100
WindowsCurrentVersion                                   : 6.3
WindowsEditionId                                        : ServerStandard
WindowsInstallationType                                 : Server
WindowsInstallDateFromRegistry                          : 05/02/2019 14:13:23
WindowsProductId                                        : 00377-70126-52438-AA588
WindowsProductName                                      : Windows Server 2016 Standard
WindowsRegisteredOrganization                           :
WindowsRegisteredOwner                                  : Windows User
WindowsSystemRoot                                       : C:\Windows
BiosCharacteristics                                     : {3, 9, 15, 16...}
BiosBIOSVersion                                         : {VRTUAL - 1, Hyper-V UEFI Release v1.0, EDK II - 10000}

And so on.....
```

yet run the same command within ISE and it returns a different set of variables;

```
ComputerName       : DEV
OSName             : Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard
OSVersion          : 10.0.14393
MemoryGB           : 4
NumberOfProcessors : 1
NumberOfSockets    : 1
NumberOfCores      : 8
```

- Windows Server 2016 Standard
- PowerShell version 5.1.14393.206

Do I need to load any modules into ISE ?

Comment: And your programming related question is?

Comment: You should also indicate the version of PowerShell that you're using, and the version of Windows you're using - for example, on PS5.1 on Windows 7SP1, `Get-ComputerInfo` throws an error about a missing entry point in kernal32.dll; on PS4 on WinServer 2012R2, the cmdlet doesn't exist at all.

Comment: On my 2012R2 and Windows 10, running it in the ISE returns the same string as in a normal PowerShell host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there are two commands available within ISE. Get-ComputerInfo and Get-ComputerInfo

[image]

When you insert into ISE one inserts

> Get-ComputerInfo

which was the one I was hitting and the other is

> Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Get-ComputerInfo

which is the one I wanted. My script now work in ISE and Console